# Linux: increase sda1 partition size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I want to  increase sda1 partition in my vm because its almost full. 
I choosed dynamic size in virtualbox, but it doesn't seem to work (the size don't increase dynamicaly).
Here partitions state

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            610M     0  610M   0% /dev
tmpfs           126M  4,2M  122M   4% /run
/dev/sda1       6,6G  5,6G  619M  91% /
tmpfs           629M   92K  629M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           629M     0  629M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           126M   12K  126M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I resized partition size through windows with command line, i've got 15GB free, but when i tried to boot on a live cd of gparted, I can't resize sda1 because there is another partition between the `sda1` partition and the greyed not used 15GB.

I tried command `resize2f` but it tells me that sda1 doesn't have the block I asked for.

Edit : result of command `sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 16,8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  7232MB  7231MB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      7233MB  8589MB  1356MB  extended
 5      7233MB  8589MB  1356MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Is is possible to increase sda1 without deleting everything ? I already backed up my vm.
thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, The dynamic size option in Virtualbox just means the file that stores the virtual disk on the host will grow when needed, up to the limit you specified. You still need to tell the guest OS to resize the partition. Anyway... A more helpful output might be from the command "sudo parted -l" assuming parted is installed on your system.

Comment: You're right, sda1 part can't do more than 8gigs anyway, this is why VBox didn't increase the storage.
I edited my question with the result of the command

Answer (score 1):

There probably is an easier way but this is what worked for me while I was looking to increase my Fedora Vbox VM's HD size (from 20GB to 30GB). 
YMMV.

1. Resize hard disk image (VDI, Dynamically expanding) (say, to 30GB) from the windows host

   > ```
   > C:\> "C:\Program Files\Oracle VM VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd C:\VM\Fedora\Fedora.vdi --resize 30720
   > ```
2. Boot from gparted live iso-mounted CD

   > ```
   > + gparted (in my case) showed 10GB of unallocated space and a 20 GB root partition.
   > + Deactivated the 20GB root partition and resized all the way till 30GB.
   > ```
3. Booted back the Fedora VM, 'df -h' continued to show the older 20GB as my disk-space.

   > ```
   >    $ df -h
   >    Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   >    /dev/mapper/fedora-root              18G   17G  165M 100% /
   >    devtmpfs                            366M     0  366M   0% /dev
   >    tmpfs                               372M   80K  372M   1% /dev/shm
   >    tmpfs                               372M  720K  372M   1% /run
   >    tmpfs                               372M     0  372M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   >    tmpfs                               372M   20K  372M   1% /tmp
   >    /dev/sda1                           477M   85M  363M  19% /boot
   > ```
4. Used the instructions from here to resize LVM - http://www.tcpdump.com/kb/os/linux/lvm-resizing-guide/all-pages.html

   > ```
   > Resize Logical Volume
   >    $ sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root
   > Resize ext4 volume using 'resize2fs'
   >    $ sudo  resize2fs -p  /dev/mapper/fedora-root
   > ```
5. Booting back to the Fedora VM, 'df -h' should now show the root partition to have increased.

   > ```
   >     $ df -h
   >     Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   >     /dev/mapper/fedora-root              28G   17G  9.7G  64% /
   >     devtmpfs                            366M     0  366M   0% /dev
   >     tmpfs                               372M   80K  372M   1% /dev/shm
   >     tmpfs                               372M  720K  372M   1% /run
   >     tmpfs                               372M     0  372M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   >     tmpfs                               372M   20K  372M   1% /tmp
   >     /dev/sda1                           477M   85M  363M  19% /boot
   > ```